How do I create a Test toll free verification in twilio?
I am building an app that uses Twilio. Currently the app is in development. I have not deployed it to a server yet. When I attempt to create a trusthub profile it is denied because we havent deployed the site to a public URL. Before I deploy, I want to ensure the app handles all errors correctly. I have set up phone numbers, subaccounts, and now need to test toll free verification. Twilio does not have any documentation showing how to test the toll free verification before deployment. Surely They do not expect you to deploy an app first to production then pay money and wait months for responses to test toll free verification? that could take a year to handle all edge cases. Twilio test credentials do not work for creating toll free verifications. You can create MOCK 10DLC brands and campaigns. How do I create MOCK or TEST toll free verifications?
